# Cannot dynamically save user.is_active in Django UpdateView form_valid, or signal

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have two models, `User`(extends `Abstract User` and inherits `is_active` field) and `Supervision` connected to User with Generic Foreign Key.
When we save an instance of Supervision, the code must check the `suspended` field on the Supervision instance and update `user.is_active` to contrary.
I am failing to save save the user instance, as it reverts back to True and saves twice.
Here is my code from `form_valid()`:

```
suspension, created = Suspension.objects.get_or_create(
            content_type = ContentType.objects.get(app_label="myapp", model="suspension"),
            object_id = self.kwargs['pk'],
        )
suspension.reason = form.cleaned_data['reason']
suspension.suspended = form.cleaned_data['suspended']
suspension.save()
user = suspension.content_object
user.is_active = False if suspension.suspended else True
user.save()
return super().form_valid(form)
```

Here is my signal:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Suspension, weak=False, dispatch_uid=uuid.uuid4())
def suspend_unsuspend_user(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    from userprofile.models import User
    if isinstance(instance.content_object, User):
        user = instance.content_object
        user.is_active = instance.suspended 
        user.save()
```

UPDATE: overwriting save() on `Suspension` model to update User instance

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    from userprofile.models import User
    if isinstance(self.content_object, User):
        try:
            user = self.content_object
            user.is_active = False if self.suspended else True 
            user.save()
        except:
            raise RuntimeError('Unable to find user')
    return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

**NONE works!**

While implementing them separately, I get the user instance saved twice and every time user.is_active reverted back to True and saved (i.e. a post_save signal on User instance prints it twice, always True in the end). I have checked my code, I do not touch user.is_active anywhere else.
Also I can change is_active from admin or shell.
What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in `form_valid()` method.
The problem was caused by the code saving the suspension separately before `super().form_valid(form)`.
The code worked by changing it to this:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    suspension, created = Suspension.objects.get_or_create(
            content_type = ContentType.objects.get(app_label="myapp", model="suspension"),
            object_id = self.kwargs['pk'],
        )
    suspension.reason = form.cleaned_data['reason']
    suspension.suspended = form.cleaned_data['suspended']
    form.instance = suspension # <-- here's the solution: we overwrite the form.instance and let django do its job.
    user = suspension.content_object
    user.is_active = False if suspension.suspended else True
    user.save()
    return super().form_valid(form)
```